# Python y QtDesigner (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

Quiero pedir "n" datos al usuario, anteriormente en modo consola los datos los almacenaba en un arreglo y los pedía mediante un "for" 
Ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
n=int(input("Numero de datos:")) 
array=np.zeros((n))

for i in range (1,n):
   array[i] = int(input("Valor número"+str(i)+":"))
```

pero ahora intento hacerlo de forma gráfica y no se de que manera pedir estos datos para almacenarlos en el arreglo, pensé en hacerlo con una tabla pero eso implicaría agregar una tabla con el "n" número de filas y no tengo idea de como hacerlo.Soy principiante en python junto a PyQt5. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Una QTableWidget puede valer para esa tabla, y en el constructor le indicas el nº de filas y de columnas, siendo el nº de filas el valor "n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentalo ejemplo:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, 
                             QPushButton, QApplication, QSpinBox)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Numero de datos:")

        self.input1 = QSpinBox(self)
        self.input1.setMinimum(1)
        self.input1.setMaximum(12)
        self.input1.setValue(3)
        
        self.pushButton_ok = QPushButton("Press me", self)
        self.pushButton_ok.clicked.connect(self.addtextbox) 

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.input1, 0, 5)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_ok, 0, 10)

    def addtextbox(self):
        countLayout = self.layout().count()
        if countLayout > 3:
            for it in range(countLayout - 3):  
                w = self.layout().itemAt(3).widget()
                self.layout().removeWidget(w)     
                w.hide()
        self.lineEdits = []   

        for n in range(self.input1.value()):
            self.bursttime = QLabel(self)
            self.bursttime.setText("Valor número {}".format(n))
            
            self.timeinput = QLineEdit(self)
            self.timeinput.textChanged.connect(lambda text, i=n : self.editChanged(text, i))

            self.grid.addWidget(self.bursttime, 2*n+1, 0)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.timeinput, 2*n+1, 1)
            
            self.lineEdits.append('')  

        self.go = QPushButton("GO") 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.go, 2*n+2, 0)
        self.go.clicked.connect(self.printvalues)
      
    def printvalues(self):  
        array = np.zeros((self.input1.value()))                      # n <--> self.input1.value()
        for i, v in enumerate(self.lineEdits):        
#            print("Valor número {}: {}".format(i, v))  
            array[i] = int(v) if v else 0                            # array[i]
            
        print(array)

    def editChanged(self, text, i):
        self.lineEdits[i] = text    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(250, 180)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]